# Save and Update Record date wise in via Django Rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I am new to django , I am using AIPView method of restframework to create and update leaderboard model. The requirement is to save Email, Name and Total Score along with a date field which automaticall updates the date each time the record is saved.

Each time a users score his highest score , its pushed to database on server. A user can achieve higest score many times within a single day or within of a few days

The issue is that my client wants to save highest score record date wise.

I am able to update total Points everytime I receive from the client for the current dateand I am unable to keep the previous days hights score/TotlaPoints, Please advice a solution.

[Please click to see how the admin section looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moD21.png)

This is my Models.py file

```
  class leaderboard(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(_("playername"), max_length=255)
     email = models.CharField(_("email"), max_length=255, default='myemail@gmail.com')
     TotalPoints = models.IntegerField(_("TotalPoints"))
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)code here
```

This is my Views.py file: I tried following code but it only saves the highest score to Total_points field and updates the date field (updated_at), I want to keep on updating Total Points until the dat changes, when the next day comes a new entry for the same record should be done but with diff date and  Total Point. To sum it up I want to keep each day's highest score for each user .  Please help.

```
    from .models import leaderboard as leaderb
import datetime

# Create your views here.

class UpdateLeaderboard(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['get','post']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = leaderboardSerializers(leaderb.objects.all()[:2], many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, format = None):

        serializer = leaderboardSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.validated_data['name']
            email = serializer.validated_data['email']
            TotalPoints = serializer.validated_data['TotalPoints']


            today = datetime.date.today()

            if leaderb.objects.filter(updated_at__date = today) and leaderb.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                
                serializer = leaderb.objects.get(email=email)
                serializer.name = name
                serializer.TotalPoints = TotalPoints
            else :
                serializer.email = email
                serializer.name = name
                serializer.TotalPoints = TotalPoints



            serializer.save()

        return Response(None, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class Leaderboard(APIView):

    def get(self, request, formate=None, **kwargs):
            today = datetime.date.today()
            serializer = lwithcdateSerializers(leaderb.objects.filter(updated_at__date=today).order_by('-TotalPoints')[:40], many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is serializers.py file

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import leaderboard



class leaderboardSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = leaderboard
        fields = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'TotalPoints',



            ]


class lwithcdateSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = leaderboard
        fields = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'TotalPoints',
            'updated_at',
            ]enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save Highest Points to a separate table that is related to Leaderboard.